# Working with third party components in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am currently using [vue-simple-uploader](https://github.com/simple-uploader/vue-uploader).  So far it has been pretty straight forward, I have my component set up

```
<uploader :options="options" ref="uploader" id="churn" @file-complete="fileComplete" @complete="complete">
    <uploader-unsupport></uploader-unsupport>
    <uploader-drop>
        <p>Please upload 1 file</p>
        <uploader-btn :attrs="attrs" :single=true>select files</uploader-btn>
    </uploader-drop>
    <uploader-list></uploader-list>
</uploader>
```

And I have my script

```
<script>
    import uploader from 'vue-simple-uploader'

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                reportType: '',
                options: {
                    target: 'api/upload',
                    testChunks: false,
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
                    }
                },
                attrs: {
                    accept: '.csv'
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            complete () {
                console.log('complete', arguments)
            },
            fileComplete () {
                console.log('file complete', arguments)
            },
            isComplete () {
                console.log(arguments)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

So in the most part this works.  The file is sent in chunks to my API route and saved.  My API is sending back the response

```
return response()->json([
    'path' => $filePath,
    'name' => $fileName,
    'mime_type' => $mime
]);
```

And I now want to check this on the frontend.  `vue-simple-uploader` has a isComplete {Boolean} scoped slot on the UploaderFile component, which apparently returns the server response.  I am not sure however how I can use this?  I have found the original code [here](https://github.com/simple-uploader/vue-uploader/blob/master/src/components/file.vue) but how do I actually check the server response to see the result?

As you can see, I have tried creating a isComplete method, but that currently does nothing.

Any advice appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `isComplete`, try using the [`fileSuccess`](https://github.com/simple-uploader/Uploader#events) method instead whose third argument comes from the server.

Taken from the [docs](https://github.com/simple-uploader/Uploader#events):

> `.fileSuccess(rootFile, file, message, chunk)`: **A specific file was
>   completed.** First argument rootFile is the root Uploader.File instance
>   which contains or equal the completed file, second argument file
>   argument is instance of Uploader.File too, it's the current completed
>   file object, **third argument message contains server response. Response
>   is always a string.** Fourth argument chunk is instance of
>   Uploader.Chunk. You can get response status by accessing xhr object
>   chunk.xhr.status.

I had an experience with a similar situation but with a different library so I'm not sure if this will work.